# Assigning Multiple Template Values to a Variable in Django

Tags: html, django

I need to assign multiple values from a dictionary to a variable in a Django template.

i.e

```
fruit.supplier = tesco 
fruit.color = blue

{% with test=fruit.supplier_fruit.color  %}
    {{ test }}
{% endwith %}
```

The result for the `test` variable should be `tesco_blue`.

However this doesn't work. I can assign the variable if I just use `fruit.supplier`. But I'm unsure how to assign multiples.

Comment: What is fruit.supplier? What do you get when you print `fruit.supplier` *and* `fruit.supplier_fruit.color`?

Comment: question is not clear can you describe more  what you want to do ?

Comment: Why are you doing this in the template?

Comment: You are correct I should of been. In the end. This is what I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should of been doen on the view. Once I did this everything worked and processed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{{ fruit.supplier }}_{{ fruit.color }}
```

No need for the `with` statement.

**Update**

Using the `with` statement.

```
{% with test=fruit.supplier|add:"_"|add:fruit.color %}
    {{ test }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: but i need to assign this to a variable. Any further ideas ?